# How to filter DB query with OR in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to structure a `WHERE question LIKE 'Who%' OR question LIKE 'What%'`  SQL query from inputs of a POST request.
What is the correct way to do this?

If `showall` POST value is `True` then no next filter needs to be matched. All entries returned.
If `showall` is `False` then combine the next filters for the `OR` statement to return entries matching only of the filters provided.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
from django.db.models import Q
def getuserlist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        showall = request.POST['showall']
        showfl_1 = request.POST['showfl_1']
        showfl_2 = request.POST['showfl_2']

        if showall == 'true':
            filt = Q(listing=any)
        elif showfl_1 == 'true':
            filt = Q(listing="Filtered1")
        elif showfl_2 == 'true':
            filt = filt | Q(listing="Filtered2")

        searchresult = list(User_data.objects.filter(listing=filt).values_list("Country","gender","listing").order_by('-added_date'))
   return searchresult
```

Comment: By using `elif`, you never will perform *both* checks

Comment: You can use the `|=` operator to combine two `Q` objects queries with OR: `filter |= Q(attr=value)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Will fix that. It didn't work on the first `elif` either.

Comment: It is furthermore not entirely clear to me *how* the filtering should behave: if none of `showall`, `showfl_1` and `show_fl2` are checked? Then what is the expected result?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `showall` to select all entries, irrespective of next filters. If filters are `True` then apply `OR` on those filters. Entries to be returned for any of those filters matched.

Comment: Note that `request.POST` does *not* contain booleans. If you marked the checkbox, then the key is in the `request.POST`, otherwise it is missing. So `request.POST['foo']` will error if you did not check a checkbox with name `foo`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Checkbox sends  true or false like this `showall = $("#showall").prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @KapishM: `request.POST` can not contain *booleans*, the HTTP format simply is not designed for this. It can send a string `'true'`, or a *string* `false`, but both are thus strings, and both have truthiness `True`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Modified it for `if showall == 'true':` No change.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `Q` object that is a disjunction of the options:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

if showall != 'true':
    filters = []
    if showfl_1 == 'true':
        filters.append(('listing', 'filtered1'))
    if showfl_1 == 'true':
        filters.append(('listing', 'filtered2'))
    if not filters:
        searchresult = User_data.objects.none()
    else:
        searchresult = Q(*filters, _connector=Q.OR)
else:
    searchresult = User_data.objects.all()

searchresult = list(searchresult.values_list(
    'Country','gender','listing'
).order_by('-added_date'))
return JsonResponse({'data': searchresult})
```

Comment: Interesting. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
from django.db.models import Q
def getuserlist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        showall = request.POST['showall']
        showfl_1 = request.POST['showfl_1']
        showfl_2 = request.POST['showfl_2']
        c = {}
        if showall:
            c['listing']= Q(listing=any)
        elif showfl_1:
            c['listing']= Q(listing="Filtered1")
        elif showfl_2:
            c['listing'] = Q(listing="Filtered2")

        searchresult = list(User_data.objects.filter(**c).values_list("Country","gender","listing").order_by('-added_date'))
   return searchresult
```